# DraweeView scale fit width

Tags: android, scale, fresco

How can I scale an image loading into a `DraweeView` so that the width is always fitted?

The `DraweeView` is configured like this:

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="X dp"/>
```

with `"X dp"` meaning some fixed amount of `dp`. The image's height should be cropped if it doesn't fit in the `View`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a scale type for this, see http://frescolib.org/docs/scaling.html

In your case, `centerCrop` should work:

Add this to your Drawee in XML: `fresco:actualImageScaleType="centerCrop"`

In Java:

```
GenericDraweeHierarchyBuilder builder = ... // your builder
builder.setActualImageScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

If you need more complex scaling, you can also implement your own scale type that extends `AbstractScaleType` and set it in Java.